# Is ist possible to get a MemoryMXBean instance with a remote JVM?

Tags: java, mbeans

I found this nice article which explains how to query your current memory for your VM http://recursor.blogspot.com/2006/10/memory-notifications-in-java.html

My question is, is it possible to get an instance of the MemoryMXBean class from a remote VM easily (and how would I do that), or do I have to resort to query the MBeans manually?

Answer (score 2):

as described on [this page](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/package-summary.html#examples) you can access it remotly, with the `MBeanServerConnection`:

```
   MBeanServerConnection mbs;

   // Connect to a running JVM (or itself) and get MBeanServerConnection
   // that has the JVM MXBeans registered in it
   ...

   try {
       // Assuming the RuntimeMXBean has been registered in mbs
       ObjectName oname = new ObjectName(ManagementFactory.RUNTIME_MXBEAN_NAME);

       // Get standard attribute "VmVendor"
       String vendor = (String) mbs.getAttribute(oname, "VmVendor");
   } catch (....) {
       // Catch the exceptions thrown by ObjectName constructor
       // and MBeanServer.getAttribute method
       ...
   }
```

however, as far as I understand, you won't be able to use the Java interface, you'll need to query the properties you want with

```
CompositeDataSupport mem = (CompositeDataSupport)serv.getAttribute(memory, "NonHeapMemoryUsage") ;
```

and

```
mem.get("committed")
```

which is quite awfull ('stringly-typed' interface, as they said in another question).

As Brian Agnew said, the JConsole view is very usefull to find out where the information you want is stored.

Comment: Thanks. You solved a cast exception I was getting when using the proxy MemoryMXBean interface over JMX. This should be voted as the answer. You can expand your answer with a mapping to MemoryUsage: MemoryUsage memoryUsage = MemoryUsage.from(mem);

Answer (score 1):

You can query JMX beans remotely. See the [JMX Connectors](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jmx/tutorial/connectors.html#wp5529) section in the JMX tutorial.

The straightforward approach may be to use [JConsole](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html) to determine what you want to query (in this case your MemoryMXBean) and then code around that.